AWS API Gateway returning 400 Bad Request when query parameter is encoded JSON
I have a REST API setup in API Gateway that integrates with a Lambda to route incoming requests to another external REST API. It is essentially a passthrough function from our API to another legacy API. The external API allows for a query parameter with a JSON value and I want my API to accept a JSON value too and pass through to the legacy API but I am getting a 400 Bad Request error. I am using Postman for testing which is set to auto encode. I know it is an encoding issue but not sure where those settings might be. I have Lambda proxy integration turned on for this resource.
So, in Postman if I send this request:
https://test.my.api.com/users?id={"email":"test.user@mail.com"}

It actually transforms/encodes to send this:
https://test.my.api.com/users?id={%22email%22:%22test.user@mail.com%22}

Which works just fine with the legacy API. But my API returns 400.
The only way it works for my API is to use EncodeURIComponent to fully encode the value:
https://test.my.api.com/users?id=%7B%22email%22%3A%22test.user%40mail.com%22%7D

The client should be able to simply switch endpoints to point to my API without changing any of their legacy requests/queries but I am stumped.

Hard to say anything without seeing some code. Log what your lambda receives and what it sends to the legacy API

This is before the request reaches the lambda. But even the API logs are not showing the incoming request.

AWS API gateway don't support { character in request URL.
More information can be found here: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/api-gateway-known-issues.html#api-gateway-known-issues-rest-apis

The plain text pipe character (|) and the curly brace character ({ or
}) are not supported for any request URL query string and must be
URL-encoded.


Exactly what I was looking for, thank you!
